# I am making a form that submits the data to a text file, how do i make it go to a certain directory?(its my first time)

Tags: php, html

Hi I am currently making a website and I have two main files index.hml and action_page.php I am trying to get the HTML form to send the data to a file but I don't know how to set a directory. Heres the code

```
(HTML code)
         <div class="messageform">
          <form action="action_page.php" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

(PHP Code)

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['firstname'] ) && isset( $_POST['lastname'] ) )
{
    $txt= $_POST['firstname'].' - '.$_POST['lastname'] . PHP_EOL; 
    file_put_contents('fields.txt', $txt, FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: and where do you want to store the file?

Comment: I made a folder /text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the directory in the file path itself or as a variable/constant if repeated.

example of in file path

```php
file_put_contents('./path/to/file/here/fields.txt', $txt, FILE_APPEND);
```

the `./` is relative location to where the php file is executing the function.
to go back a level you would use `../path/to/dir` or multiple levels would be `../../path/to/dir`

VS Code helps make navigating those ../‘s a little easier with autocomplete in your workspace.

The other method would be to use a variable:

```php
$TextFilePath = ‘./path/to/dir’;

file_put_contents(“$TextFilePath/fields.txt”, $txt, FILE_APPEND);
```

To add onto what was posted while i was typing.  i don’t know how to type their name, sorry.  They added a validation check, but used the filename for path creation.  To see if the directory existed before attempting to write to it — which can throw an error.  this is good practice and missing from your function.

my final - final proposed answer
*note: this is what we tested to work in DM*

```php
<?php
if( isset($_POST['firstname'] ) && isset( $_POST['lastname'] ) ) {
    // Manage our constants easier up top in one place
    $TextFilePath = './text/';
    $FileName = 'fields.txt';
    $FullPathAndFileName = "$TextFilePath$FileName";

    // Create our data to write
    $txt = $_POST['firstname'].' - '.$_POST['lastname'] . PHP_EOL; 
    
    // Validate dir exists, if not, create it
    if (!is_dir($TextFilePath))
        mkdir($TextFilePath, 0755, true);

    // Open/create our file to write to
    $file = fopen($FullPathAndFileName, "w") or die("Can't find or create $FileName");

    // Write out the form data
    fwrite($file, $txt);

    // Close the file
    fclose($file);
}
```

### Image of written file and created directory

[View screenshot of written file and created directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmf1w.png)

*note*
I just want to note too.  @RickyS was having file permission issues on the web server, causing more questions to be asked than how to add a directory path.  This code above has been tested & debugged to verify its accuracy for what was asked of it to do.

*This is RickyS I agree and I also thank Ryan for helping me :) *

Comment: I tried just now like this file_put_contents('var/www/html/field.txt') but no file was created?

Comment: I tried your final answer and it gave me HTTP error 500?

Comment: you are using the root path, not the relative path.  I am not sure if that is affecting things or not.  It is generally accepted you should use relative paths to the location of your php file.

Comment: oh snap, sorry, you are also missing your contents for the file in your comment.  is that on purpose?

Comment: here you go, i think this page will certainly have the answer for you. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: nope dunno how to do it hehe. Could u please tell me?

Comment: Tell you this?  `file_put_contents('./html/field.txt', $txt, FILE_APPEND);` *note* this is assuming that /var/www/ is the directory your php file is saved in.

Comment: Hey, that confused me even more :) I know you need to state what u want to include but still no idea how the things I need to include is the firstname and lastname would I just go  include_path"firstname,lastname"?

Comment: Now i’m confused, and am about to ask you to DM to resolve it and post our results back.  Last try: you already have the contents for the file being created in variable $txt.  FILE_APPEND means don’t overwrite the file.  You need a directory path and a filename and ext. `/var/www/html/field.txt` is your provided path.  phpFile.php is in `/var/www` which you read now as `./` which is your root path. `html` is your directory/folder path. `field = fileName` `txt = really?` together `${path}/${filename}.${extension}` you use `’./html/field.txt’, $txt, FILE_APPEND);` better?  i’m trying.

Comment: I think if you literally changed this line to be `$TextFilePath = ‘/var/www/html’;` then you could just copy/paste my final answer and it work.

Comment: Can we DM. And also I got confused when you said "oh snap, sorry, you are also missing your contents for the file in your comment. is that on purpose? –" also thanks for helping so far

Comment: @RickyS DM on twitter @ devnetkc I can’t find a way to DM you on here.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])) {

            $txt = $_POST['firstname'] . ' - ' . $_POST['lastname'] . PHP_EOL;

            $path = "/tmp/user/fields.txt";

            if (!is_dir(dirname($path)))
                mkdir(dirname($path), 0755, true);

            file_put_contents($path, $txt, FILE_APPEND);
        }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I also tried your code and although it looked like it worked I checked the directory, and the file either isn't there or wasn't created at all?

Comment: I've changed it
```
file_put_contents($path, $txt, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: I tried yours again and it looked like it worked again but still no file.